# Questions about interacting with contracts using truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a simple Escrow contract that I've deployed using testrpc. I'm not sure how to interact with the methods once I've created an initialized a new one.

Here's the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Escrow {

address public buyer;
address public seller;
address public arbiter;

  function Escrow(address _seller, address _arbiter) {
    buyer = msg.sender;
    seller = _seller;
    arbiter = _arbiter;
}

  function payoutToSeller() {
    if(msg.sender == buyer || msg.sender == arbiter) {
      seller.send(this.balance);
    }
}

  function refundToBuyer() {
    if(msg.sender == seller || msg.sender == arbiter) {
      buyer.send(this.balance);
    }
  }

  function getBalance() constant returns (uint) {
    return this.balance;
  }
}
```

Console returns the following when I create a new instance of my escrow contract:

```
Escrow.new([acct2, acct3]).then(function(instance) { console.log(instance.address);})
0x7982e782f1f3937d7b626691b11216155b6b47d0
undefined
```

So it seems to have worked. My question is how do I interact with that contract to send it some value? Similar to how I would with a deployed `MetaCoin` contract using something like `MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) { return instance.sendCoin(acct1, 10, {from: acct2});})`?

Also, who is the `msg.sender` in this case?

Thank you for any help.

UPDATE - Setting `address =  Escrow.new([acct2, acct3]).then(function(instance) { return instance.address;})`

Trying to add contract address to `Escrow.at(address)` and receiving the following error `Error: Invalid address passed to Escrow.at(): [object Promise]`. Also have tried `Escrow.at(address).get()` and getting the same error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in order for your contract to accept eth you need to implement a [fallback function](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function):

```
function() payable {}
```

Then you can send some eth to your contract:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:accounts[0], to:"YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS", value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
```

And call contract methods:

```
Escrow.at("YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS").payoutToSeller({from:acct3});
```

This call follows your example using `acc3` which was defined as `arbiter` in contract constructor as the account who publish the transaction.

Comment: Thank you Jakub. Having an issue still.
`address = Escrow.new([acct2, acct3]).then(function(instance) {return instance.address;})` returns `'0xcc63a4e6d0c487476719972fb4b6b70b0cdd646d'`

When I `web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:acct1, to:address, value:web3.toWei(1, "ether")});` I'm getting `Error: invalid address`. I've added the fallback function and recompiled everything.

Comment: I see. You need to assign the address inside the body of promise: Escrow.new([acct2, acct3]).then(function(instance) { address = instance.address;})

Comment: That worked. Thank you! One more question if you don't mind. Who is msg.sender when I call the `new()` method?

Comment: If you don't put an object that specifies the sender {from: SENDER} in the constructor it's going to be the default account: web.eth.accounts[0].