# Interacting with a deployed contract: How can I mint a token based on the Open Zeppelin Standard

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, crowdsale

Please excuse what seems to me a basic question, as I am very new to this:

I'm using the truffle framework to deploy a smart contract. Playing around with Open zeppelin standard tokens, I've issued the *SampleCrowdsale.sol* contract: [Link](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/examples/SampleCrowdsale.sol)

I've successfully got it on the *Ropsten* blockchain, but that's as far as my knowledge goes. How can I interact with the contract, other than sending ether to it?

As an owner, how can I call the **mint** function that's part of the *MintableToken.sol* contract?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Interacting with smart contracts using truffles](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19474/questions-about-interacting-with-contracts-using-truffle/19478).

If you deployed your smart contract with the name SampleCrowdsale, for example with

```
var mycrowdsale = SampleCrowdsale.deployed();
```

then you have access to the function mint():

```
mycrowdsale.mint(to, amount);
```

with *to* as the receiver address and *amount* the number of tokens created.

You can also check it works with:

```
mycrowdsale.mint(to, amount).then(function(balanceOf(to)) {
  // If this callback is called, the call was successfully executed.
  // Note that this returns immediately without any waiting.
  // Let's print the return value.
  console.log(balance.toNumber());
}).catch(function(e) {
  // There was an error! Handle it.
})
```

balanceOf is a standard ERC20 function.

You can look at this [Interacting with your contracts](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/contracts/#executing-contract-functions) tutorial where I took the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try calling `mycrowdsale.mint(to, amount);` I get: `TypeError: sc.mint is not a function`

I'm calling the contract through: `var sc = SampleCrowdsale.at("0x...");`

Answer (score 0):

```
    erc20ContractName receiver = erc20ContractName(contractAddress);
    var isOkToCall = receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
    var myBalance = receiver.balanceOf(msg.sender);
```

Polymorphism / How to interact with deployed contract / ERC20 tokens
... how to call functions in deployed contract /how to call deployed token erc20 contract solidity

See similar question: [How does this code from ERC223 standard implementation work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/how-does-this-code-from-erc223-standard-implementation-work/35727#35727)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps :

1. Test using following command

   `truffle test`
2. Compile :

   `truffle compile`
3. Develop :

   `truffle develop`
4. Deploy and create an instance and accept that instance in a variable as follows :

   `SampleCrowdsale.deployed().then(function(instance) {app = instance})`

Now you can use this variable `app` to access all the functions inside the contract.

Ex: `app.mint(to, amount);`

[Source : Truffle Framework](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/project#testing)